# Entity Framework SQL not optimal on navigation property

Tags: asp.net-mvc, performance, entity-framework

I have simple code first model (generated from db) with 3 entities:

```
[Table("Note")]
public partial class Note
{
    public Note()
    {
        NoteCompanies = new HashSet<NoteCompany>();
    }

    public long ID { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "text")]
    public string Content { get; set; }

    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<NoteCompany> NoteCompanies { get; set; }

}

[Table("Company")]
public partial class Company
{
    public long ID { get; set; }

    [StringLength(150)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

}

[Table("NoteCompany")]
public partial class NoteCompany
{
    public long ID { get; set; }

    public long NoteID { get; set; }

    public long CompanyID { get; set; }

    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }

}
```

When i use this Model inside ASP MVC View like:

```
@model Models.Note

<ul>
@for (var company in Model.NoteCompanies.Select( nc => nc.Company ))
{
   <a href="#">@company.Name</a>
}
</ul>
```

Entity framework fires single select query for each Company. I would expect that Entity would use produce `JOIN` query like:

```
SELECT {fields} 
FROM 
  NoteCompany NC
  INNER JOIN Company C ON NC.CompanyId = C.Id
WHERE
  NC.NoteId = @Param
```

Is it possible to force EF to produce `JOIN` query instead of single row `SELECT`?

Best Regards
IT Man

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be better to write something like this:

```
@{
    var ids = Model.NoteCompanies.Select(nc => nc.CompanyID).ToList();
    for (var company in db.Companies.Where(x => ids.Contains(x.ID)).ToList())
    {
       <a href="#">@company.Name</a>
    }
}
```

Or try to get `NoteCompanies` with corresponding `Companies` at controller via `eager loading`:

```
model.NoteCompanies = db.NoteCompanies.Include(x => x.Company).ToList();
return View(model);
```

Comment: Thanks, works! Is it possible to achieve this behaviour on entity level (Note)? I would like to have a property that will return related companies with single query run.

Comment: I think the only ways are shown above, anything else will be wrapings about those.